# Problem when running iOS project on my jailbroken iPhone with Xcode: Error: SpringBoard not linked into application

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging, jailbreak, tweak

When I want to run my iOS project on my jailbreak iPhone I get this error:

> objc[23503]: class 'SpringBoard' not linked into application

my app stock hang and couldn't stop the installing process in Xcode even. Xcode complained about these tweaks: DataMeter, Flex3, and LibertyLite and I get some success after uninstalling theme but my problem has appeared again. now I can run my project on my iPhone in "safe Mode" but in normal mode I can not.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Go to unc0ver in a jailbroken state and toggle “Refresh Icon Cache” and respring to run uiCache properly

Comment: thanks for answer but it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: you have to redo the jailbreak

Comment: I do redo but no success.